# Combining for and if loops together

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

New to programming and reading a how to book.  Question is about loops.  I have the following code:

```
public bool DoThisJob(string job, int numShift) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentJob))
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < jobsICanDo.Length; i++) {
            if (jobsICanDo[i] == job) {
                currentJob = job;
                this.shiftsToWork = numberOfShifts;
                shiftsWorked = 0;
                return true;
            }
        return false;
```

If the currentJob string is not empty then return false or return true? There is no **else** statement so how do we know what to do if it is true?.

Next run a **for loop** and again is the for loop ran because it returned false or true?  Last run an if statement which is self explanatory.

Comment: `return` immediately stops execution of the method. This is usually called a guard statement. It's functionally equivalent to wrapping the entire method in `if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentJob)) { /* everything */ } else { return false; }`. Neither way is right or wrong, though I personally prefer guard statements for their readability.

Comment: Actually there is an else statement.  The else statement is the entire `for loop`.  I would read more of your programming books.

Answer (score 1):

There is no else because of the "return" statement. It immediately aborts execution of the function and returns to the calling function. You could write it with an else and it will function the same.

Comment: It doesn't need an else because you only want to do something specific  for one of the cases. For everything else you want the rest of the code in the method to run. It's similar to doing `if (arg == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("arg");` to guard for invalid arguments in a method.

Answer (score 0):

`There is no else statement so how do we know what to do if it is true?.`

in an `if ... else` (or classically called `if .. then .. else`) construct `else` if optional and in its absence it would fall through to the next statement outside the `if` block, in this case its the `for` statement

Your above function can be equivalently though to be similar to

```
public bool DoThisJob(string job, int numShift) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentJob))
            return false;
        else {
            for (int i = 0; i < jobsICanDo.Length; i++) {
                if (jobsICanDo[i] == job) {
                    currentJob = job;
                    this.shiftsToWork = numberOfShifts;
                    shiftsWorked = 0;
                    return true;
                }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the currentJob string is null then the `if` statement won't be run, and it will fall through to the `for` loop.

If the conditions in the `for` loop trigger it to return true then the method returns true and the last return is never reached.

If the `for` loop doesn't return true it will fall onto the last line and the method will return false.

Answer (score 0):

A return statement stops the execution of the function at that point and returns control to the calling procedure.

```
public bool DoThisJob(string job, int numShift) {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentJob))
            return false; // If it is not empty then function call returns from this statement

        // Else, flow control falls through and below code is executed
        for (int i = 0; i < jobsICanDo.Length; i++) {
            if (jobsICanDo[i] == job) {
                currentJob = job;
                this.shiftsToWork = numberOfShifts;
                shiftsWorked = 0;
                return true;
            }

        return false;
        }
```

I hope, this clarifies the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your function can be simplified as follows without a loop;

```
public bool DoThisJob(string job, int numShift) {

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(currentJob) || !jobsICanDo.Contains<string>(job))
    {
       //if currentJob NOT null/empty OR 
       //job is not in the jobsICanDo[] array
       return false;
    }
    else
    {
        currentJob = job;
        this.shiftsToWork = numberOfShifts;
        shiftsWorked = 0;
        return true;
    }
}
```